# Closed form for Jacobi sum $\sum_{a\in \mathbb{F}_{p^2}}\chi(a)\chi(1-a)$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, characters

Let  $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ be a field with $p^2$ elements and $\chi:\mathbb{F}_{p^2}^*\to\mathbb{C}^{*}$
be a multiplicative and non-trivial character on the multiplicative group $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}^*$ (extended by $\chi(0)=0$). Let $$J(\chi)=\sum_{a\in \mathbb{F}_{p^2}}\chi(a)\chi(1-a).$$ Is it possible to find a closed form for $J(\chi)$?

---

Writing that whole sum makes sense and is very similar to what you do in the $\mathbb{F}_p$ case.

However, I doubt that this generator approach will be useful here. As you already noted, this completely takes into account the multiplicative structure of our field, but none of the additive structure. And the appearance of $1-a$ really makes this an additive problem. So essentially you are summing $\chi(ab)$ over $a,b$ with $a+b=1$. And it is completely hopeless to characterise the solutions to such an equation in terms of a multiplicative generator.
Compare to how primitive roots are useful to find the number of quadratic residues but completely useless to find e.g. the number of adjacent quadratic residues i.e. numbers where $a$ and $a+1$ are quadratic residues.

Comment: Is $p$ prime? or just a prime power? Also there is clearly no such character, unless you mean a character $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}^*\to\mathbb{C}^*$, or mean it to be valued in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: I don't think there is any closed-form formula, no.

Comment: This is a Jacobi sum $J(\chi,\chi)$ (for the field $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$). One reference is http://www.math.mcgill.ca/goren/SeminarOnCohomology/mycohomologytalk.pdf.